# localhost can't find file even though it exists (HTTP ERROR 500), MAMP server

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I've recently installed MAMP, and localhost can't find the index file when I open the subdirectory even though it exists (HTTP ERROR 500).

My localhost is set to 90 in Apache. I've tried 80 and 8888, but none works. I am able to load `localhost:90` correctly, but whenever I enter a subdirectory like http://localhost:90/01_FirstPage/, it can't find the index.php even though it exists.

**This is the error in the log:**

> [04-Oct-2023 05:53:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [04-Oct-2023
> 05:53:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Failed opening required
> 'C:/Users/[user]/OneDrive/Documents/U/Web Programming 2/PHP
> course/CodeDynamicWebsites/CodeDynamicWebsites/01_FirstPage/index.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

I also tried another browser. The code in the index file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First PHP Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php print('Hello World!'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which directory that `http://localhost:90` points to?

Comment: @BadPiggie It's C:\Users\[User]\OneDrive\Documents\U\Web Programming 2\PHP course\CodeDynamicWebsites\CodeDynamicWebsites if I understood the question correctly. Apologies, I am just beginning a course regarding this theme today.

Comment: It seems unusual, to me anyway, that you are using your profile documents folder like that. Is that set as the document root?

Comment: not too familiar with MAMP but it must have an .htaccess file or some equivalent. can you post its contents? possibly a permissions issue

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes, that's the document root. How should I do it in any case?

Comment: @greysaff What do you mean by its contents?

Comment: @starfish greysaff means the contents of the .htaccess file in that folder, or in the website root, if you have one

Comment: **M**AMP but "C:/...", what does the first M stand for?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks! I did some research on that and found out the folder in MAMP would be C:\MAMP\htdocs. I just replaced the content inside the folder with the files I needed, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @shingo What do you mean?

Comment: I just thought M stands for Mac, so why does the path on a Mac start with "C:/"?

Comment: That's true. MAMP stands for Mac originally, although I see at https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/ they have now released a Windows edition. The original Windows version of the same concept is called WAMP (https://www.wampserver.com/en/). Or there's XAMPP which is cross-platform. Anyway glad you fixed the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was following a tutorial on Udemy, so I changed the original directory when I first installed MAMP to a personal folder, and it wasn't working. After the comments mentioned `.htaccess`, I looked up where to find this folder in MAMP. For Windows, it is saved in `C:\MAMP\htdocs.`

I reset the directory and `localhost` to its default in MAMP (`C:\MAMP\htdocs.`, and apache: `8888`), and tried loading `localhost:8888` again. It all loaded perfectly with the `index.php` file inside `htdocs`, so I replaced the content inside the `htdocs` folder with the files I needed and done!